# "Slope" in mathematics and " slope" in economics.

Tags: terminology, economics, slope

Note : I mainly consider the case in which demand curves are linear , to keep things simple.

---

I'm having trouble in applying mathematics to (micro)economics due to the fact that in this discipline , the independent variable is standardly placed on the Y axis (while it is placed on the x axis in mathematics).

In economics, we are presented with demand curves.

My question deals with the meaning of the "slope" of such curves.

A demand curve is supposed to represent a demand function (with price as independent variable, on the Y axis) $ D = f(P)$.

The "gradient" of this function is given by  $ \frac {\Delta D} {\Delta P}$   (or its limit in the non-linear case). .

But when  we calculate the slope of the demand function we do it "the ordinary ( mathematical ) way", that is we calculate the ratio  "rise over run"  :  $ \frac {\Delta P} {\Delta D}$.

***So is it correct to say that , in fact, the slope of the demand curve ( or of its tangent in case the curve is not linear) is not the gradient of the demand function, but in fact, the inverse of the gradient of the demand function?***

Example :  Let the demand function be  $D(p) = -2p+10$ . The gradient of this function is $-2 = -2/1$ but the slope of the demand curve is $1/-2 = - 1/2$.

Comment: Yes, you’re correct.

Comment: In economics elasticity is a more important concept than slope. $E = - \frac {\Delta Q}{\Delta P} \frac {P}{Q}$